# What determines the data type that PostgreSQL filters on?

Tags: postgresql, precision

I'm quite familiar with how IEEE 754 single precision and double precisions data types have their suprizes. I've read the articles on what every computer scientist should know a about floating point arithmetic, but I'm puzzled about a choice that Postgresql makes.

I create a table

```
create table ttt(f4 float4, f8 float8, fn numeric);
```

I add some values:

```
insert into ttt (f4,f8,fn) values(12.206,12.206,12.206);
```

I do a query:

```
select count(*) from ttt where f4=12.206;
 count 
-------
     0
(1 row)
```

I ask for an explanation:

```
gsh=# explain select count(*) from ttt where f4=12.206;
                        QUERY PLAN                        
----------------------------------------------------------
 Aggregate  (cost=23.77..23.78 rows=1 width=0)
   ->  Seq Scan on ttt  (cost=0.00..23.75 rows=6 width=0)
         Filter: (f4 = 12.206::double precision)
(3 rows)
```

So  the query is trying to match the double precsion version 
of 12.206 to the value stored as single precsion, and they aren't 
matching, which isn't a surprise.

What is a surprise to me is that since by default postgresql
seems to treat numbers as numeric:

```
gsh=# select 12.206;
 ?column? 
----------
   12.206
(1 row)

gsh=# select pg_typeof(12.206);
 pg_typeof 
-----------
 numeric
(1 row)
```

If numbers are by default treated as numeric, why isn't the filter comparing
against 12.206 as a numeric instead of a double precision? I find this a violation of least surprise.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be explained with the [type resolution rules for operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-oper.html).

As you correctly observe, the type at the left side of the `=` operator in your expression is `real`, and the type on the right side is `numeric`.

There are implicit casts from `numeric` to `double precision` and `real` and from `real` to `double precision` (check with “`\dCS`” in `psql`).
If you examine the available `=` operators (check with “`\doS =`” in `psql`), you will find that after step 3.a. the following operators remain:

```
real             = double precision
double precision = double precision
```

In step 3.c., the first of there operators is chosen, because it matches the left input type exactly.

You can force the use of the `real = real` operator by using a `real` constant, like in

```
... WHERE f4 = 12.206::real
```

or

```
... WHERE f4 = REAL '12.206'
```